# how to replace values of an individual row and specific columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with 902 columns. I want to replace all the values of row 0 from columns 214 to 902 by the values stored in a list. For instance:

I have a list like this:

```
list_a=['item0','item1','item2', 'item3'....'item 688']
```

I have a data frame like this:

```
 item0 item1 item2 item3 ...item688
0  x.    y.    z.    w.       i
1  x.    y.    z.    w.       i
2  x.    y.    z.    w.       i
3  x.    y.    z.    w.       i
4  x.    y.    z.    w.       i
```

my desired output is:

```
  item0 item1 item2 item3 ...item688
0 item0 item1 item2 item3 ...item688
1  x.     y.    z.    w.       i
2  x.     y.    z.    w.       i
3  x.     y.    z.    w.       i
4  x.     y.    z.    w.       i
```

Note: The items stored in the list are also the names of the data frame columns from 214 to 902

I tried, but that does not work:

```
df.iloc[0,214:902] = list_a
```

How can I achieve this goal? Any help I appreciate!!

Comment: Is item `688` your last column?

Comment: I think it's just a slight mistake in your slicing, try `iloc[0, 214:]`

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew 688 is the last item of the list. The last column is not 902 because the dataset contains other columns I added later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok that is very strange than your solution works with this simple test:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colA':[True, False, False], 
    'colB': [1, 2, 3],
    'colc':[True, False, False], 
    'colD': [1, 2, 3]
})

df.iloc[0, 1:3] = ['test 1', 'test 2']
```

The resulting data frame changed from:

```
    colA    colB    colc    colD
0   True    1   True    1
1   False   2   False   2
2   False   3   False   3
```

to:

```
    colA    colB    colc    colD
0   True    test 1  test 2  1
1   False   2   False   2
2   False   3   False   3
```

That would solve your problem if i am not mistaken right?
Can you check or verify your results some how again?

A possible problem might arise with your iloc command because if you want to change column 902 as well, you would have to say `df.iloc[0, 212:903]`.
You could check this with `len(df.iloc[0, 1:3])` and `len(list_a)` to verify that they have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

My solution works:

```
df.iloc[0,214:902]= list_a
```